# Non Repeatable Read from database table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose I have a table 100 rows, I just want to select top 10 rows of table, but my situation is that i want to select only those rows which was not previously processed.
For this i have added a Flag column so that i will update whenever i process rows.

But here the problem arises when concurrent request comes for top 10 rows. Both may get same rows and trying to update the same rows (which I dont want to do).

Here I can't use Begin Transaction because It will lock the table and concurrent request will not get handled.

> Requirement : My actual requirement is When i am selecting top 10 rows
>   using flag condition and updating then, then if other request for the
>   same it will also select other top 10 rows which is not handling by
>   Request 1.

```
Example : My table contains 100 rows.
{
Select top 10 * from table_name where flag=0

update table_name set top 10 flag = 1 
}
(Will select top 10 out of 100 rows n update)


if at the same time during above request, another request come,
{
Select top 10 * from table_name where flag=0 (Should skip previous request rows)

update table_name set top 10 flag = 1 
}
Need: (Will select top 10 out of rest 90 rows n update)
```

I Need a lock on top 10 rows of first request, but lock should like skip rows of first request even during **simultaneous select statement of both requests**

Please help me out for this to solve.

Comment: Thanx Ameya for rephrasing the question. Can you please help me out for this?

Comment: 1. Simultaneous is a fiction of our imagination. 2. What do you REALLY need? is it ok if the first request locks the entire table for a very short period of time (milliseconds or less), and that the next request will wait for that part to finish before picking it's own group of 10 rows?

Comment: @Amit : I dont want to lock the entire table as I mentioned in Question. In this way it will do like one by one fashion. I just need a optimized way assuming 1 Million total rows in the table . So one by one fashion might be time consuming task. Morever, I Need non repeatable reads. Is there any way that it will select only those rows which havn't read before. Sorry for such long description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an [OUTPUT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause to do both the selecting and the updating the flag in one statement, e.g.

```
UPDATE TOP 10 table
SET flag = 1
WHERE flag = 0
OUTPUT inserted.*
```

Comment: @dean : I have come to know about readpast hint. But does it prevent selection of rows which is getting modified by transaction 1, instead I need that anothers can able to select another 10 rows instead of that 10 rows which is getting updated by transaction 1 concurrently

Comment: if a row is locked by update in one transaction, the second transaction's update will skip that row without waiting - I assume it was your intention, right?

Comment: yeah @dean : this was the clarification i Needed., I was confused whether Another transaction skip those rows and read rest top 10 or it will just read but will not able to update.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you don't want to use a Transaction because it will lock the table for the duration of the update.

Maybe you could split the process into one part which selects the rows and updates the flag and a second part where you actually do your update with the selected rows.

Use a Transaction only for the first part of the task. This will ensure the table is only locked for the absolute Minimum of time.

As for your non-repeatable reads:

If you really want enforce this policy you should delete the selected row from the table and optionally save them to another table where the read-history stays. The lowest-level way to accomplish this guaranteed is with an update of another flag (updated?) and a trigger after the update.

```
Transaction with ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ
{
    select top 10 rows
    update select-flag
    return the 10 rows
}

normal query
{
    take the returned 10 rows and do something
    change updated-flag
}

Trigger after update if updated-flag changed
{
    copy updated to read-history-table
    delete updated-rows
}
```

[ISOLATION LEVELS on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx)

> REPEATABLE READ "Specifies that statements cannot read data that has
>   been modified but not yet committed by other transactions **and that
>   no other transactions can modify data that *has been read by the
>   current* transaction until the current transaction completes**."

Comment: Here is like, during select both request will get the same data, but at a time one request update the data, But during lock 2nd request will wait to complete the transaction, after that it will again update the same rows not modification actually. Ultimately both request getting same rows, that i dont want. Thanks for your such nice explanation but it didn't meet my requirement.

Comment: @VikrantMishra - Your comment is wrong, and this answer is what I suggested in my comment. Please try to pay more attention to understand this as it will probably do what you need.

Comment: @KarmaEDV : I have read this ISOLATION Level but does this Repeatable Read isolation prevent reading of record by transaction 2 which is process by Transaction 1.

Comment: @VikrantMishra Yes, please try it. An upvote would be appreciated ;)

Comment: @KarmaEDV : thanls for your answer. but m new here so not able to upvote as my reputation points are less. :) thanks alot